# Как создать представлениe, котороe отображаeт данные на момент вставки без последующих обновлений?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Можно ли создать материализованное представление, которое будет только инкрементным?

Хотел бы, чтобы старые данные, которые уже были вставлены, были без обновлений. То есть, представление должно отображать состояние данных только на момент вставки.

Если это возможно, то как это можно сделать?

Какой раздел документации могу использовать в качестве руководства?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Create an incremental view where old data is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68218719) от участника [@AllPower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5491043/allpower)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68218719

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите увидеть состояние данных **каждой** записи на момент вставки, то короткий ответ:

*Нет, не получится.*

Материализованное представление (MV) хранит результат запроса в том виде, в котором он существует *сейчас*, а не когда-то в прошлом. Поэтому, после обновления записи можно либо увидеть ее текущие значения, либо исключить ее из MV.

Если задача, сохранить/просмотреть состояние данных на момент вставки, есть несколько путей решения:

- Сделать таблицу только для вставки (возможно, сохраняя историю изменений внутри таблицы).
- Перехватывать данные при вставки (например, с помощью триггера) сохраняя их в другой таблице.
- Использовать [Flashback Data Archive](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-06AA782A-3F79-4235-86D5-2D136485F093) для хранения истории изменений и просматривать ее с помощью [Flashback Query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-0BD1F4BD-894B-47BA-A44B-74BCA4CFD60E).

Какое из этих решений наиболее подходящее, зависит от того, зачем нужен просмотр данных на момент вставки.

---

Технически возможно просматривать данные на момент вставки до определенного момента времени.

С помощью [Flashback Version Query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-544C00A0-D4F5-4B32-BE2F-5332EDCDD039) можно просмотреть изменения в таблице спустя какое-то время. То есть, сделать примерно следующее:

```
create table t (a int, b int, created timestamp, changed timestamp);
/* как минимум 15 сек. пауза после создания таблицы */

insert into t values ( 1, 1, systimestamp, systimestamp );
insert into t values ( 2, 2, systimestamp, systimestamp );
commit;
        
create materialized view mv as 
    select t.*
    from t 
    versions between scn minvalue and maxvalue
    where versions_operation = 'I'
/

update t set b = 9, changed = systimestamp
where a = 2;
insert into t values (3, 3, systimestamp, systimestamp );
commit;

select * from t;
    
         A          B CREATED                     CHANGED                    
---------- ---------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
         1          1 09.09.21 21:54:31,146997000 09.09.21 21:54:31,146997000
         2          9 09.09.21 21:54:32,715374000 09.09.21 21:58:03,465860000
         3          3 09.09.21 21:58:30,158792000 09.09.21 21:58:30,158792000

select * from mv;

         A          B CREATED                     CHANGED                    
---------- ---------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
         3          3 09.09.21 21:58:30,158792000 09.09.21 21:58:30,158792000
         2          2 09.09.21 21:54:32,715374000 09.09.21 21:54:32,715374000
         1          1 09.09.21 21:54:31,146997000 09.09.21 21:54:31,146997000
```

При этом используется UNDO для восстановления истории. Со временем старые изменения исчезнут, и снова будет доступно только текущее состояние. По умолчанию можно получить только изменения за **последние 15 минут** (см. параметер `undo_retention integer 900`).

Если нужно хранить историю в течение более длительного периода времени, *Flashback Data Archive* - это то, что нужно. Начать можно, например, с [примеров в этом блоге](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531159) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>